# Flip TPath shape data horizontally

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

How To flip a TPath shape component data ? i have loaded a path data from an SVG image, but the shape is flipped, i want to flip it horizontally.

i tried to do the `Canvas.CopyRec` method but that is a VCL method i suppose.

```
var src, dest: TRect;
begin
  dest:=bounds(0, 0, image1.Picture.Width, image1.Picture.Height);
  //src:=rect(0, image1.Picture.Height-1, image1.Picture.Width-1, 0); // Vertical flip
  //src:=rect(image1.Picture.Width-1, 0, 0, image1.Picture.Height-1); // Horizontal 
  flip
  src:=rect(image1.Picture.Width-1, image1.Picture.Height-1, 0, 0); // Both flip
  image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.CopyRect(dest, image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas, src);
```

i'm using Firemonkey and Delphi 10.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution for a horizontal flip can be made via a negative value in the property Scale.X of the component *TPath*.

```
Path1.Scale.X := -1;
```

For a vertical flip use `path1.Scale.Y := -1;`